# Non-expiring sessions in Padrino

Tags: session-state, padrino

I've made a Padrino app that has one single password for accessing the admin page. I'm using the following helpers for the authorization.

```
# Check if the user is authenticated.
def authenticated?(opts = {})
  if session["cooly"] != options.session_secret
    redirect url(opts[:send_to] || :login)
  end
end

# Create a new session.
def authenticate!
  session["cooly"] ||= 0
  session["cooly"] = options.session_secret
end
```

Write now, when I exit my browser, the session goes away and I have to login again. How do I keep the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to make non-expiring *cookies*.

```
# Check if the user is authenticated.
def authenticated?(opts = {})
  if session["cooly"] == options.session_secret || request.cookies["cooly"] == options.session_secret
    return true
  else
    redirect url(opts[:send_to] || :login)
  end
end

# Create a new session.
def authenticate!
  session["cooly"] ||= 0
  session["cooly"] = options.session_secret

  expiration_date = 10.year.from_now

  response.set_cookie('cooly', :value => options.session_secret, :expires => expiration_date)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the in your app `session_secret`

`set :session_secret, 'fc29ce0f33f0c8cde13f3'`

Answer (score -1):

Check out: https://gist.github.com/977690 and that should resolve the issue.